# Keeping an entity variable after update

Tags: c#, binding, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a table of companies with the standard columns like Id, Name, CompanyNumber + + + 
but I also got an Active flag as well as a Created timestamp, and I do not want neither of those fields to be editable, so I removed them from the View, but that means that after binding the model both Active and Created are set to default values.

I know several ways to solve this, currently I am retrieving the entity from the database first, setting the values manually into the new one and then updating the new one.

But is there a better way? Or is the other option to publish both values into the View and then have asp.net bind it for me?

Answer (score 0):

if they are not editable then you don't want to send them to the view to then set them and update them manually.  Retrieving the record first is a good approach otherwise you have to always set every property.  That isn't a good solution.